# How to find probability of occurrence of $E$ given $A$ said $E$ occured?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

$A$ speaks the truth with probability $p$. An event $E$ occurs with probability $\alpha$. I have to find the probability of occurrence of $E$ given that $A$ said $E$ occured.

My approach:

$P[E|A_E] = \frac{P[A_E|E]P[E]}{P[A_E|E]P[E] + P[A_E|E^c]P[E^c]}$

Now I have to find $P[A_E|E]$ and $P[A_E|E^c]$ from the following information

$P[A_E|E]P[E] + P[{A_E}^c|E^c]P[E^c] = p$,

$P[A_E|E^c] + P[{A_E}^c|E^c] = 1$,

$P[A_E|E] + P[{A_E}^c|E] = 1$

But I could not find any way. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If A speaks truth with probability p, if he says E occurred it did occur with probability $\alpha$.  If A does not speak the truth with probability (1-p), if he says E occurred then it did not occur with probability $1-\alpha$.

Now $$P(E/\text{A says E occurred}) = \frac{\alpha p }{\alpha p + (1-\alpha)(1-p)}$$